# Redirect page if found some string in URL - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a function which suppose to redirect a user if `/resources/` string is found in url of page he's trying to visit,
but it's not working, can someone tell me what went wrong?

```
function redirect_collateral() {
if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/resources/") !== false){
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$my_var = '';
$url = str_replace("/resources/", $my_var, $url );
header("Location: $url");

    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'redirect_collateral' );
```

Answer (score 2):

1. using str_contains():

```
function redirect_to_resources() {
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if ( str_contains( $uri, '/resources/' ) ) {
        $my_var = '';
        $uri    = str_replace( '/resources/', $my_var, $uri );
        wp_safe_redirect( $uri );
      }
    }
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_resources' );
```

2. using strpos():

```
function redirect_to_resources() {
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if ( strpos( $uri, '/resources/' ) == true ) {
        $my_var = '';
        $uri    = str_replace( '/resources/', $my_var, $uri );
        wp_safe_redirect( $uri );
      }
    }
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_resources' );
```

Comment: `str_contains` is only available from PHP 8, for previous versions use `strpos`

Comment: @MosheGross Okay, Please check my both answers.

Comment: `wp_safe_redirect` will be best to use in this case instead of using `wp_redirect` since we're redirecting in the current host. Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/#user-contributed-notes

Comment: @VijayHardaha, Absolutely.